# Cython: understanding a typed memoryview with a indirect_contignuous memory layout

Tags: python, cython, typed-memory-views

I want to understand more about Cython's awesome [typed-memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) and the memory layout `indirect_contiguous`.

According to the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#specifying-more-general-memory-layouts) `indirect_contiguous` is used when *"the list of pointers is contiguous"*.

There's also an example usage:

```
# contiguous list of pointers to contiguous lists of ints
cdef int[::view.indirect_contiguous, ::1] b
```

So pls correct me if I'm wrong but I assume a *"contiguous list of pointers to contiguous lists of ints"* means something like the array created by the following c++ dummy-code:

```c
// we want to create a 'contiguous list of pointers to contiguous lists of ints'

int** array;
// allocate row-pointers
// This is the 'contiguous list of pointers' related to the first dimension:
array = new int*[ROW_COUNT]

// allocate some rows, each row is a 'contiguous list of ints'
array[0] = new int[COL_COUNT]{1,2,3}
```

So if I understand correctly then in my Cython code it should be possible to get a memoryview from a `int**` like this:

```py
cdef int** list_of_pointers = get_pointers()
cdef int[::view.indirect_contiguous, ::1] view = <int[:ROW_COUNT:view.indirect_contiguous,COL_COUNT:1]> list_of_pointers
```

But I get Compile-errors:

```
cdef int[::view.indirect_contiguous, ::1] view = <int[:ROW_COUNT:view.indirect_contiguous,:COL_COUNT:1]> list_of_pointers
                                                                                                        ^                                                                                                                              
------------------------------------------------------------

memview_test.pyx:76:116: Pointer base type does not match cython.array base type
```

what did I do wrong?
Am I missing any casts or did I misunderstand the concept of indirect_contiguous?

Comment: This might not be possible with just a cast - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465091/assembling-a-cython-memoryview-from-numpy-arrays which seems to construct the buffer-interface manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's set the record straight: typed memory view can be only used with objects which implement [buffer-protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-protocol).

Raw C-pointers obviously don't implement the buffer-protocol. But you might ask, why something like the following quick&dirty code works:

```
%%cython    
from libc.stdlib cimport calloc
def f():
    cdef int* v=<int *>calloc(4, sizeof(int))
    cdef int[:] b = <int[:4]>v
    return b[0] # leaks memory, so what?
```

Here, a pointer (`v`) is used to construct a typed memory view (`b`). There is however more, going under the hood (as can be seen in the cythonized c-file):

- a [cython-array](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/692a742127681b86cf4edcaa5cfa981b59e175cd/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L105) (i.e. `cython.view.array`) is constructed, which wraps the raw pointer and can expose it via buffer-protocol
- this array is used for the creation of typed memory view.

Your understanding what `view.indirect_contiguous` is used for is right - it is exactly what you desire. However, the problem is `view.array`, which just cannot handle this type of data-layout.

`view.indirect`  and `view.indirect_contiguous` correspond to  [`PyBUF_INDIRECT`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.PyBUF_INDIRECT) in protocol-buffer parlance and for this the field [`suboffsets`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.Py_buffer.suboffsets) must contain some meaningful values (i.e `>=0` for some dimensions). However, as can be see in the [source-code](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/692a742127681b86cf4edcaa5cfa981b59e175cd/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L105) `view.array` doesn't have this member at all - there is no way it can represent the complex memory layout at all!

Where does it leave us? As pointed out by @chrisb and @DavidW in your other question, you will have to implement a wrapper which can expose your data-structure via protocol-buffer.

There are data structures in Python, which use the indirect memory layout - most prominently the PIL-arrays. A good starting point to understand, how `suboffsets` are supposed to work is [this piece of documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#pil-style-shape-strides-and-suboffsets):

```
void *get_item_pointer(int ndim, void *buf, Py_ssize_t *strides,
                       Py_ssize_t *suboffsets, Py_ssize_t *indices) {
    char *pointer = (char*)buf;    // A
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ndim; i++) {
        pointer += strides[i] * indices[i]; // B
        if (suboffsets[i] >=0 ) {
            pointer = *((char**)pointer) + suboffsets[i];  // C
        }
    }
    return (void*)pointer;  // D
}
```

In your case `strides` and `offsets` would be

- `strides=[sizeof(int*), sizeof(int)]` (i.e. `[8,4]` on usual `x86_64` machines)
- `offsets=[0,-1]`, i.e. only the first dimension is indirect.

Getting the address of element `[x,y]` would then happen as follows:

- in the line `A`, `pointer` is set to `buf`, let's assume `BUF`.
- first dimension:

  - in line `B`, `pointer` becomes `BUF+x*8`, and points to the location of the pointer to x-th row.
  - because `suboffsets[0]>=0`, we dereference the pointer in line `C` and thus it shows to address `ROW_X` - the start of the x-th row.
- second dimension:

  - in line `B` we get the address of the `y` element using `strides`, i.e. `pointer=ROW_X+4*y`
  - second dimension is direct (signaled by `suboffset[1]<0`), so no dereferencing is needed.
- we are done, `pointer` points to the desired address and is returned in line `D`.

---

FWIW, I have implemented a library which is able to export `int**` and similar memory layouts via buffer protocol: https://github.com/realead/indirect_buffer.

Comment: allright, thank you very much for the detailed explaination. I'm going to dig into the details of the buffer-protocol